# Simulated Metrics size for "iPhone 5.5-inch" doesn't show the interface correctly in iPhone 6 plus device

Tags: ios, iphone, user-interface, iphone-6-plus

I'm using xcode 6.1.1 version and iPhone 6 plus as testing device. I simply add a button at the right side of my xcode user interface, selecting `Simulated Metrics` size for `iPhone 5.5-inch` like this :

[image]

But when I run this on device the button goes far away from the right edge. Like this (Snap shoot from my device):

[image]

But when I select `Simulated Metrics` size for `iPhone 4.7-inch` like this :

[image]

It shows accurately in my device. Like this (Snap shoot from my device):

[image]

I tried with selecting and un selecting `Auto Layout` & `Size Classes` but do not get any clue. My device is `5.5 inch` iPhone 6 plus. I even recheck it from my iPhone's packet and by `IMEI Number`. My question is why it is acting like iPhone 6 interface?? Is it for any reason of retina display or non retina display?? 
Thanks a lot in advanced.

My button's Constraints:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the button/ view you want. Then simply use the shortcut `⌥⇧⌘=`. This will `Reset to Suggested Constraints`.

For this to work successfully, try moving your button to the suggested areas, i.e. move the button/ view to the top right corner like you have till the dotted blue lines appear.

Once done it should show what you expect on the interface builder but to be sure test on the simulator and/ or Device.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes, It's now showing perfectly both in Device & Simulator. :)
What was the reason it wasn't worked?

Comment: It was the constraints, or lack of. It was probably squashing the view or moving it mostly off screen.

Comment: So, from now I've to make my design according to `constraints`. :)

Comment: Mastering `auto layout` (use of constraints) is really hard at first (I'm still learning too), but when you do, then you will love it. Apple uses it, and they want all of their developers using it too. It is why they have a square as the default size in `Simulated Metrics` even though there is no square iPhone screen.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the proper constraints. Using simulated metrics is only for setting things up in IB, it has no effect on what the view looks like at run time. You should leave that setting at inferred.

If you don't add constraints yourself, the system adds them for you, and it adds top, left, height, and width constraints; that is not what you want. You need to add constraints to the top and right side. If you do that, the button will appear with that spacing to the right side, no matter what size screen you're using.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. But still I used to work un selecting `Size Classes`. And select storyboards with fixed size. Then what would be the solution in this case?

Comment: @Tulon, it should work without side classes turned on, as long as you made the correct constraint. Click on your button, and go to the size inspector to look at your constraints. There should be  a constraint that says "Trailing space to superview" with a value underneath. Do you have one that says that? What is the value?

Comment: Sir, I was updated my post yesterday. It would be really great if you keep continue from the half done point. :)

Comment: @Tulon, what is the problem now? It looks like you have a proper constraint, and you've already accepted an answer, so I don't know what more explanation you need.

Comment: @ rdelmar Ok, Sir. I appreciate your perspective. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use constraints to solve the problem but i don't know the exact cause of this

Ctrl + drag from the item to the border in the storyboard to add constraints